# SVG background on link - animating once on hover

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG set as a background image for a link. When you hover over the link the SVG is displayed and the animation is played once and then stops. This works great, except when you hover over the link a second time (or any other link with the SVG background), the animation doesn't start over.

Is there a way (other than setting the animation to loop) to get the SVG to start again on each hover? This is the code for the SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="All_glyphs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="10px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 10 20" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect x="0" y="20" width="10" height="20" fill="#7fffe5">
        <animate attributeName="y" from="20" to="0" dur="500ms" fill="freeze" repeatCount="0"/>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

And the CSS I use:

```
a:hover {
    background-image: url(link.svg);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. When you hover for the first time you're loading the image which triggers the animation after that the image is already loaded.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. I was wondering if there was a way to do it, as it's an SVG. I'm going to have a play with CSS embedded in the SVG with hover states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used background-position and CSS transitions to animate the background.